# Why am I getting ones when evaluating the runge function at chebyshev points?

Tags: matlab, math, polynomial-math

I cannot understand why my output y is all 1's. Please help, I've been staring at this for hours. It works perfectly in another similar program where I choose equally spaced points.

```
function [t,y] = chebyshev(n)

format long

for k = 1:1:n
    r = ((2*k - 1)*pi)/2*n;
    t(k,1) = cos(r);
end

for j = 1:1:n
    y(j,1) = (1/(1 + (25*(t(j,1)^2))));
end
figure(3)
plot(t,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying by `n` in your first loop; you need to wrap the denominator in parentheses:

```
function [t,y] = chebyshev(n)

format long

for k = 1:1:n
    r = ((2*k - 1)*pi)/(2*n);
    t(k,1) = cos(r);
end

for j = 1:1:n
    y(j,1) = (1/(1 + (25*(t(j,1)^2))));
end
figure(3)
plot(t,y);
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I needed to use cosd() instead of cos().
Good.

Comment: cosd() is used if input to the function is in degrees and cos() is used when input is in radians.